# Undesired behavior onClick modal(pop-up) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently I'm trying to learn JavaScript basics through making mini projects, right now i have met some roadblocks while working on a note taking app.

Here is my main issue:

1.) After exiting the modal i can no longer see the note added only the 'view detail' button.

p.s. please share any ideas of optimizing or improving the overall readability of the code.

**THANK YOU FOR YOUR REPLY!!**

HTML FILE:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Note Taker</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="headings">
            <h1 class="title">Note Taker</h1>
            <h3 class="sub-title">Add A New Note:</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="user_input">
            <label for="note">Note:</label>
            <textarea type="text" id="note" placeholder="Write your note here" rows="4" cols="70"></textarea>
            <br><button type="submit" id="btn_addNote">Add Note</button>
        </div>
        <div class="onClickContainer" id="onClickContainer">
            <p id="empty">No notes added yet!</p>
        </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="modal" id="modal">
        <div class="modal-header" id="modal-header">
            <button class="close-button" id="close-button">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript File:

```js
let addNoteButton = document.getElementById("btn_addNote");
let closeBtn = document.getElementById('close-button');
let inputBox = document.getElementById("note");
let notesContainer = document.getElementById("onClickContainer");
let emptyText = document.getElementById("empty");
let overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");

addNoteButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    
    if(inputBox.value.length !== 0){

        let newNote = document.createElement('div');
        newNote.className = 'note';

        let noteTitle = document.createElement('h2');
        noteTitle.className = 'note-title';

        let noteText = document.createElement('p');
        noteText.className = 'note-text';
        noteText.innerText = inputBox.value;

        let noteBtn = document.createElement('button');
        noteBtn.className = 'detail-btn';
        noteBtn.innerText = 'view detail';

        newNote.appendChild(noteTitle);
        newNote.appendChild(noteText);
        newNote.appendChild(noteBtn);

        notesContainer.appendChild(newNote);
        if(notesContainer.contains(emptyText)) {
            notesContainer.removeChild(emptyText);
        }   

        let getTitles = document.querySelectorAll('.note-title');
        let titlesArr = Array.from(getTitles);
        let counter = 0;
    
        for(i = 1; i <= titlesArr.length; i++){
            counter++;
            noteTitle.innerText = 'Note ' + counter;
            //console.log('hello');
        }

        /*noteBtn : objectif of this function is to open a pop up when
                    clicked on view detail(button) and display the title
                    , the text and the exit symbol(x)*/
        noteBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            let modal = document.getElementById("modal");
            let modal_title = document.getElementById("modal-header");
            modal_title.appendChild(noteTitle);
            modal.appendChild(noteText);
            openModal(modal);
        });

        closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            let modal = closeBtn.closest('.modal');
            closeModal(modal);
        });

        overlay.addEventListener('click', () => {
            let modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal.active');
            modals.forEach(modal => {
                closeModal(modal);
            });
        });
        /*Function declarations should not be placed in blocks
        but i don't know where else to put them or use function expression 
        in this situation*/
        function openModal(modal){
            if (modal === null) return;
            modal.classList.add('active');
            overlay.classList.add('active');
        }

        function closeModal(modal){
            if (modal === null) return;
            modal.classList.remove('active');
            overlay.classList.remove('active');
        }

    }
    else {
        notesContainer.removeChild(newNote);
        alert('Please enter a valid note!');
    }  

});
```

CSS File :

```css
.container {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.headings{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Montserrat; 
}

.user_input{
    text-align: center;
}

textarea{
    vertical-align: top;
}

#btn_addNote{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#empty{
    text-align: center;
    width: 43%;
}

#empty {
    margin: 2rem;
    font-size: 1.3rem;    
}
/*************NOTES***********************/

#onClickContainer {
    margin-top: 3rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);
}

.note {
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.note-title {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin: 1rem 0 0.5rem 0;
}

.note-text {
    margin: 0.5rem 0 1rem 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: left;
    width: 80%;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-height: 1.1rem;
}

.detail-btn {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(46, 100, 216);
    border: 1px solid lightblue;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 2.5rem;
    width: 7rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #note{
        height: 4em;
        width: 30em;
    }
}


/*****************MODAL*******************************/


.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
    transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: white;
    width: 500px;
    max-width: 80%;
}
  
.modal.active {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
  
.modal-header {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
  
.modal-header .title {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
  
.modal-header .close-button {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: none;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
  
.modal-body {
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
  
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    pointer-events: none;
}
  
#overlay.active {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

Comment: Your post is asking three different questions.  That makes it qualify as "too broad".  Reduce your question to a single question.

Comment: I've reduced my question 